# Custom fields и woocommerce — вкладка с 500+ картинками подгружается вместе со страницей. Как исправить?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, cms, woocommerce

Вот пример, страница с товаром, под товаром есть вкладка ВЫБОР ТКАНИ. http://mebelcheap.ru/product/evroknizhka-transformer

В ней 500+ картинок. И они подгружаются вместе с сайтом, а не при открытии вкладки(там еще подвкладки в ней).

Эта влкадка сделана через custom fields. Как можно сделать чтобы подгружались эти картинки именно при клике по влкадке?

Answer (score 3):

Через `ajax`, само собой. У вас там длиннющий `html`-код во вкладке "Выбор ткани". В нем надо оставить только кнопки "0 категория" ... "Бител". При нажатии на кнопку должна срабатывать функция в `javascript`, вызывающая через `ajax` функцию `php` на сервере. Эта функция на сервере должна сформировать `html`-код для тканей запрошенной категории и вернуть его в `javascript`, где будет произведена вставка полученного на сайт, на вкладку "Выбор ткани", после всех кнопок.

Другого способа нет.

Почитать об организации ajax на WordPress можно [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Comment: Спасибо. PHP знать обязательно в данном случае, чтобы исправить или можно через Javascript/jquery сделать?

Comment: Нет, нельзя только через javascript. Вся идея в том, чтобы не грузить 500 картинок при загрузке страницы, и делать это потом, нужными частями. А где взять эти картинки в javascript и браузере, если они не загружены? Их надо у сервера запросить.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, можно его отметить, как принятый